# How does Android determine which buffer to use for logcat messages?

Tags: java, android, c++, buffer, logcat

By standard, the Android `logcat` system have 4 different ring buffers:

```
main
system
radio
events

# and alias & groups:
all      -- all available logs
default  -- main
crash    -- n/a
```

However, on AOS 6+ there seem to be other buffers as well:

```
# logcat --help
...
  -b <buffer>     Request alternate ring buffer, 'main', 'system', 'radio',
                  'events', 'crash' or 'all'. Multiple -b parameters are
                  allowed and results are interleaved. The default is
                  -b main -b system -b crash.
...
```

and the android [logcat.cpp](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/80d2f01fbf53865fdf17b776f476a48fc8ae404a/logcat/logcat.cpp#L325-L326) source code, seem to imply there are still other ones, such as:

```
security 
kernel
```

Normally in java apps, the way to put a message in `main` logcat is by using: `Log.i(TAG, msg)`.

So the question is:
**How does Android determine which buffer to use for the various logcat messages?**

(Specific references to the AOS source code would be especially appreciated.)

Then a natural follow up question would be, how can you see or enable the other *hidden* buffers?

Answer (score 8):

I don't like to answer my own questions, but I've found a few answers, and also some very good notes.

First, the various log related (Java) source files are located in:
[platform_frameworks_base/core/java/android/util/](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android/util) and in:
[platform_frameworks_base/telephony/java/android/telephony/](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/telephony/java/android/telephony).

```
EventLog.java   # EVENT Log:  These diagnostic events are for system integrators, not application authors.
Log.java        # MAIN Log:   Where user app logcat goes from:  Log.v() Log.d() Log.i() Log.w() and Log.e()
Slog.java       # SYSTEM Log: Primarily for use by coding running within the system process.
Rlog.java       # RADIO Log:  All radio, wifi, bluetooth etc. related logs. Also scrubs personal info from appearing in logs.
```

with the related files:

```
EventLogTags.java       # Deprecated! (Use EventLog)
LocalLog.java           # log(), dump(), reverseDump(), ReadOnlyLocalLog()
LogPrinter.java         #  decides what buffer to print to: LOG_ID_<buffer_name>
LogWriter.java          #  decides priority and TAG
TimingLogger.java       # A utility class to help log timings splits throughout a method call.
```

The log buffers are identified in [Log.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Log.java) by:

```
public static final int LOG_ID_MAIN = 0;
public static final int LOG_ID_RADIO = 1;
public static final int LOG_ID_EVENTS = 2;
public static final int LOG_ID_SYSTEM = 3;
public static final int LOG_ID_CRASH = 4;
```

In the OS, the logging is governed by the properties:

`setprop log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG> <LEVEL>`

and in the file **`/data/local.prop`** by:

`log.tag.<YOUR_LOG_TAG>=<LEVEL>`

Furthermore, I found the interesting comments.

The **MAIN** log:

> The order in terms of verbosity, from least to most is
>   ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, VERBOSE.  Verbose should never be compiled
>   into an application except during development.  Debug logs are compiled
>   in but stripped at runtime.  Error, warning and info logs are always kept.
>
> **Tip:** Don't forget that when you make a call like
>
> ```
> Log.v(TAG, "index=" + i);
> ```
>
> that when you're building the string to pass into Log.d, the compiler uses a
>   StringBuilder and at least three allocations occur: the StringBuilder
>   itself, the buffer, and the String object.  Realistically, there is also
>   another buffer allocation and copy, and even more pressure on the gc.
>   That means that if your log message is filtered out, you might be doing
>   significant work and incurring significant overhead.

The **EVENT** log:

> Access to the system diagnostic event record.  System diagnostic events are
>   used to record certain system-level events (such as garbage collection,
>   activity manager state, system watchdogs, and other low level activity),
>   which may be automatically collected and analyzed during system development.
>
> This is **not** the main "logcat" debugging log ({@link android.util.Log})!
>   These diagnostic events are for system integrators, not application authors.
>
> Events use integer tag codes corresponding to /system/etc/event-log-tags.
>   They carry a payload of one or more int, long, or String values.  The
>   event-log-tags file defines the payload contents for each type code.

Comment: Come on answer your own (no-good-answer) questions. The _question vote number_ vs _answer vote number_ was 3 / 3 before, and 4 / 4 now after my votes :)